# How to assign a value from a 2D list to a variable

Tags: python, list, int

I'm writing 2048 in python for class, and I keep getting the error `'int' is not subscriptable` after trying to assign the value of `sqaure[0]` to `self.textCoordinates`, and then on the next line I get the same error and again on the line beginning `self.textColour`.

```
def updateWindow(self):
    for row in gme.array:
        for square in row:
            self.textCoordinates = square[0]
            self.text = str(square[1])
            if self.text != "None":
                self.textColour = gme.colourArray[gme.numArray.index(square[1])]
                self.drawUpdate()

    updateCanvas()
```

The value of `gme.array` is:

```
    self.array = [ [[[100,100], None], [[300,100], None], [[500,100], None], [[700,100], None]],
                   [[[100,300], None], [[300,300], None], [[500,300], None], [[700,300], None]],
                   [[[100,500], None], [[300,500], None], [[500,500], None], [[700,500], None]],
                   [[[100,700], None], [[300,700], None], [[500,700], None], [[700,700], None]] ]
```

Comment: Try printing out square and seeing why python thinks it is an int.

Comment: worked fine on my system

Comment: are you sure your gme.array is the value you have provided when the method updateWindow() is called? Have you tried printing each element at the beginning of the loop to see where the values deviate from what you want?